# Faster way to set up a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r

I'm trying to set up a particular kind of sparse matrix in R. The following code gives the result I want, but is extremely slow:

```
library(Matrix)

f <- function(x){

  out <- rbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
  out <- bdiag(split(out, col(out)))
  return(out)

}#END f 

x <- outer(1:250, (1:5)/10, '+')
do.call(rBind, apply(x, 1, f))
```

I'll need to do this thousands of times in a simulation study I'm working on so this is a pretty serious bottleneck. The Rprof() output in this case was pretty confusing. I'd appreciate any suggestions you might have for how to speed things up.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It takes 2.53 seconds for me... is yours slower than that?

Comment: That's about how long it takes for me as well. The issue is that I'll need to do this perhaps 100000 times in my simulation code in addition to other operations.

Comment: > system.time(apply(x,1,f))
   user  system elapsed 
   1.12    0.00    1.13 

The bottleneck is `do.call` - is there not another way of storing the results, or do you specifically need to `rbind` them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code runs a lot faster (<0.01 seconds, vs 3.36 seconds on my box) because it avoids all of that extremely slow `rBind`'ing. The key is to first prepare the row indices, column indices, and values of the non-zero cells. A single call to `sparseMatrix(i,j,x)` will then construct the sparse matrix without requiring even one call to `rBind()`.

```
library(Matrix)
A <- 1:250
B <- (1:5)/10
x <- outer(A, B, '+')

f2 <- function(x){
    n <- length(x)
    rep(x, each=2)[-c(1, 2*n)]
}

system.time({
  val <- as.vector(apply(x,1,f2))
  n <- length(val)
  i <- seq_len(n)
  j <- rep(rep(seq_len(length(B)-1), each=2), length.out=n)
  outVectorized <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = val)
})
#    user  system elapsed 
#       0       0       0
```

Just to show that the results are the same:

```
## Your approach
f <- function(x){
    out <- rbind(head(x, -1), tail(x, -1))
    out <- bdiag(split(out, col(out)))
    return(out)
}

system.time(outRBinded <- do.call(rBind, apply(x, 1, f)))
#    user  system elapsed 
#    3.36    0.00    3.36 

identical(outVectorized, outRBinded)
# [1] TRUE
```